# How to make Tkinter buttons transparent to the background

Tags: python, tkinter

I've been trying to get a solution to this question I've looked at the documentation and videos but I haven't found anything I have a picture background as displayed in the code below and I'm just trying to make a button that will be transparent to match the background.

```
#window size
root.geometry('800x600')
#window Name
root.title('HowlBot V0.01')
#resizable false
root.resizable(width=False, height=False)
#background image

root.image = tk.PhotoImage(file=r'C:\Users\hoagl\Downloads\Background.png')
label = tk.Label(root, image=root.image, bg='black')
label.place(x=0, y=0)
```

Comment: tkinter widgets do not support transparent background.

Comment: thank you I'll just use a modified picture of the background and see how that goes